# Get birthdays a week before/during/week after

Tags: php, mysql

I have a facebook app that stores users birthday in mysql db as a varchar. Im trying to get all the users birthday that are

coming up in 1 week, 
if it's during the current week 
and if the birthday was last week.

in my php i get the birthday and convert them with strtotime()

I can easily check if the birthday is today

```
if (date('m-d') == date('m-d', $bday)) {
    // today is your bday!!
}
```

Im lost when it comes to comparing dates aahaha I know I can use strtotime('nextweek') or something like that, but im not sure

Comment: Change the data type from varchar to a proper `DATE` type. Then date manipulation becomes simple with `DATE_ADD()`, `DATE_SUB()`, etc. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Fb returns the date as a string MM/DD/YYYY if I use strtotime() before sending it to the db, what data type is it in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query would be like :

```
select * from table 
where bday between curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY and curdate() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

for the range within past week and next week.

Comment: For including the last week: `BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK`

Comment: It will include the next week. Last week is already included.

Comment: And yes, next week needs to be included. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If bday is based on the year of the person's birth, then I don't see how comparing to curdate() will ever give you an answer unless the person was less than 7 days old. =)

EDIT:

You should be able to do:

```
$bday_this_year = strtotime(date('Y')   . '-' . date('m-d', $bday));
$bday_last_year = strtotime(date('Y')-1 . '-' . date('m-d', $bday));
$bday_next_year = strtotime(date('Y')+1 . '-' . date('m-d', $bday));

$last_week = strtotime("-1 week");
$next_week = strtotime("+1 week");

if (($bday_this_year > $last_week && $bday_this_year < $next_week) || ($bday_last_year > $last_week && $bday_last_year < $next_week) || ($bday_next_year > $last_week && $bday_next_year < $next_week)) {
// Happy Birthday duders!
}
```

The reason to compute the birthday across different years is to handle the edge cases where it's late December and the user's birthday is in January, or it's early January and the user's birthday is in late December, etc.

This answer could probably be refined, but it should work.

Comment: Is it possible to have it any day last/current/next week? Lets say my bday was on may 11th 2011 (Wednesday) it should still show as your bday, even though it was "more" than a week ago

Comment: I suppose for each day of the week, you could compute your definition for last week and next week in days.  For example, today is Friday, so "last week" might be 11 days ago and "next week" might be 7 days from now.  So, for Friday, your $last_week and $next_week variables would then be strtotime("-11 days") and strotime("+7 days").

Comment: Thanks, I combined both answers and got exactly what I wanted! :)